# Moshi fail to deserialize 0, 1 to "Boolean?"

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, moshi

We try to deserialize JSON field from 0, 1, null to "Boolean?"
And we have this customize Annotation:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class BooleanType

class BooleanAdapter {
    @FromJson
    @BooleanType
    fun fromJson(value: Int): Boolean {
        return value == 1
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(@BooleanType value: Boolean): Int {
        return if (value) 1 else 0
    }
}
```

Everything works fine if the field is 0 or 1. But when it comes to "null",
it always throw exception

```
No JsonAdapter for class java.lang.Boolean annotated [@com.pk.data.serialize.BooleanType()]
....
```

Here is the dummy data and unit test

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class HaHaData(
    @BooleanType
    @Json(name = "haha") val haha: Boolean?,
)


 @Test
    fun parseNullBooleanTest() {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(BooleanAdapter())
            .build()
        val json = "{\"haha\":1}"
        val jsonWithNull = "{\"haha\":null}"
        val data = HaHaDataJsonAdapter(moshi).fromJson(json)
        val dataWithNull = HaHaDataJsonAdapter(moshi).fromJson(jsonWithNull) // exception thrown
        assert(data?.haha== true)
        assert(dataWithNull?.haha == null)
    }
```

Comment: what should the boolean be if the given value is null? Should it be null or false?

Answer (score 1):

Your `fromJson` does not accept `null` as an input.

If you want `null` to become false:

```
fun fromJson(value: Int?): Boolean {
      return 
}
```

If you want `null` to stay `null` (you'll also have to modify the `toJson` fun to accept nulls as well then):

```
fun fromJson(value: Int?): Boolean? {
    return value?.let { it == 1 }
}
```

Comment: But if I use fun fromJson(value: Int?): Boolean? {
    return value?.let { it == 1 }
}. It only apply to val haha:Boolean?, not val haha:Boolean. I want to have a adapter to deal with these cases. Is it possible?

Comment: A Boolean? is just a Boolean + possibility of null. Boolean? does not exclude Boolean.